# Upload pdf on a server with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, pdf, spring-mvc, file-upload

i try to create a web site where it will provide an option to the user to upload a pdf file. I want this pdf to be saved on the server with specific url. For example:

The user select the title.

The user upload the file.

I want after these actions the file to be accessible via a specific url/name_the_user_give.

I saw that the Spring MVC provides very easy interface for file uploading.I already see many tutorial about this but my problem is how can i save the paper into a server.Also i want the pdf to open by the browser's tools.Can anyone give me directions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save the file on server path you simply needs to write the file stream to the path described by

```
request.getServletContext().getRealPath("your directory name here");
```

and then create the file using the real path you get.

And to show the pdf file using browser plugin, you should use following in your controller method.

```
@RequestMapping(value="url to map", produces={"application/pdf"})
```

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.

Comment: Did you know a tutorial that can help me with this?

Comment: No I'm not having any tutorial right now. You just need to try it out yourself. If you stops anywhere just ask me here. :-)

Comment: at Japan Trivedi.I follow this tutorial (http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/975/spring-3-file-upload-example/) and i manage to create the upload part.Now if i want to save it in a specific folder inside my project do you know what could i do this?I want to save this with the name i give.And moreover.From this folder do you know how can i extract to browser.If you know the answer tell me to ask a new question and mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Ofcourse I will answer your question. Create a new one and then mention your problem code properly. And don't forget to include the link here in comment so that I can come to know about it. :-)

Comment: here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634799/store-a-pdf-into-the-application-file-and-extract-to-the-browser-spring-mvc   i will expect your answer.cheers