# Upload a pdf file with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload

I upload my project into a server.The files on the server are the following:

- index.jsp
- pdf
- META-INF
- WEB-INF

When i have on the localhost the way that upload the pdf's was:

```
     try{
        File file = new File("C:\\...\\pdf");
        uploadItem.getFileData().transferTo(file);
    }catch(Exception e){

        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Now i'm using this:

```
     request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/pdf");
```

But it doesn't work.Does anyone knows how can i store the pdf's into this file.And moreover if i want to retrieve a pdf file from this file what should i write?

I saw from this link: [Upload pdf on a server with Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630544/upload-pdf-on-a-server-with-spring-mvc?rq=1)

```
That i should write:

@RequestMapping(value="url to map", produces={"application/pdf"})
```

"url to map" what exactly will be?Lets say that i'm having in the pdf file:mydocument.pdf.
That mean that i have to write:

```
@RequestMapping(value="pdf/mydocument.pdf", produces={"application/pdf"})
```

Is this ok?

Comment: You can see this page:http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch16s08.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this example

http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/web/spring-3-mvc-fileupload-example.html